# How many individually different worlds can be generated in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

Pretty much all I want to know is how many different possible worlds can the Terraria world maker make. Like in Minecraft you can generate over 18 Quintillion different possible worlds from the generator.

Comment: It's probably more than a billion, so it's effectively infinite.

Comment: I think it's the number of unique map tiles the power of the product of maximum map width and height. So, a lot.

Comment: i feel like this question is probably a little too broad in a way, considering it's relatively vague and has no relevance to anything else. ***this is just an observation based on the [how to ask a good question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) site, and i could be wrong.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The official Wiki details the use of world seeds](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/World_Seed)  when generating a world. With the same seed, world size (Small, Medium or Large), Corruption/Crimson choice and difficulty (Normal or Expert), the worlds generated are guaranteed to be the same.

In other words, any difference in parameter would result in a different world. As the seeds are at most 10 digits, you are likely to have `10^10 * 3 * 2 * 2 = 120,000,000,000` different worlds, which is more than a hundred billion.

Comment: You should check this: https://youtu.be/7MxekA2GDmE?t=1791
While the intended behavior is for same seeds to always generate equal worlds, this doesn't seem to be the case: The video explains (starting at 29:54) that the jungle generation may not be consistent with the seed provided.